# Android Calculator crashing on button click

Tags: java, android, xml

Hello I have been working on an Android calculator app lately and it is almost finished, but now it is having some issues when the numbers and other operators are crashing when clicked. Then the entire app crashes. Listing code below:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/calculator_holder"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.stins.calculator.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/formula"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2.1"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:gravity="right|bottom"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin"
    android:textSize="@dimen/formula_text_size"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.8"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="@dimen/display_text_size"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_modulo"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="mod"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mod_text_size"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_power"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="^"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_root"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="√"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="C"
        android:longClickable="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_reset"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="AC"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_7"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="7"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_8"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="8"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_9"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="9"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_divide"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="÷"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_4"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_5"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="5"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_6"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="6"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_multiply"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="*"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_2"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_3"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_minus"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="-"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_0"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="0"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_decimal"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="."/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_equals"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="="/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_plus"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="+"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.stins.calculator;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.stins.calculator.Calculator;
import com.example.stins.calculator.CalculatorImpl;
import com.example.stins.calculator.Config;
import com.example.stins.calculator.Constants;
import com.example.stins.calculator.Formatter;
import com.example.stins.calculator.Utils;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import butterknife.OnLongClick;
import me.grantland.widget.AutofitHelper;

public class MainActivity extends SimpleActivity implements Calculator {
@BindView(R.id.result)
TextView mResult;
@BindView(R.id.formula)
TextView mFormula;

private static CalculatorImpl mCalc;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    CalculatorImpl calc = new CalculatorImpl(this);
    AutofitHelper.create(mResult);
    AutofitHelper.create(mFormula);
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn_plus)
public void plusClicked() {
    mCalc.handleOperation(Constants.PLUS);
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn_minus)
public void minusClicked() {
    mCalc.handleOperation(Constants.MINUS);
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn_multiply)
public void multiplyClicked() {
    mCalc.handleOperation(Constants.MULTIPLY);
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn_divide)
public void divideClicked() {
    mCalc.handleOperation(Constants.DIVIDE);
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn_modulo)
public void moduloClicked() {
    mCalc.handleOperation(Constants.MODULO);
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn_power)
public void powerClicked() {
    mCalc.handleOperation(Constants.POWER);
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn_root)
public void rootClicked() {
    mCalc.handleOperation(Constants.ROOT);
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn_clear)
public void clearClicked() {
    mCalc.handleClear();
}

@OnLongClick(R.id.btn_clear)
public boolean clearLongClicked() {
    mCalc.handleReset();
    return true;
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn_equals)
public void equalsClicked() {
    mCalc.handleEquals();
}

@OnClick({R.id.btn_decimal, R.id.btn_0, R.id.btn_1, R.id.btn_2, R.id.btn_3, R.id.btn_4, R.id.btn_5, R.id.btn_6, R.id.btn_7, R.id.btn_8,
        R.id.btn_9})
public void numpadClick(View view) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "click handler called",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    numpadClicked(view.getId());
}

public void numpadClicked(int id) {
    mCalc.numpadClicked(id);
}


@Override
public void setValue(String value) {
    mResult.setText(value);
}

@Override
public void setValueDouble(double d) {
    mCalc.setValue(Formatter.doubleToString(d));
    mCalc.setLastKey(Constants.DIGIT);
}

public void setFormula(String value) {
    mFormula.setText(value);
}

public CalculatorImpl getCalc() {
    return mCalc;
}
}
```

CalculatorImpl.java

```
package com.example.stins.calculator;

public class CalculatorImpl {
private String mDisplayedValue;
private String mDisplayedFormula;
private String mLastKey;
private String mLastOperation;
private Calculator mCallback;

private boolean mIsFirstOperation;
private boolean mResetValue;
private double mBaseValue;
private double mSecondValue;

public CalculatorImpl(Calculator calculator) {
    mCallback = calculator;
    resetValues();
    setValue("0");
    setFormula("");
}

public CalculatorImpl(Calculator calculatorInterface, String value) {
    mCallback = calculatorInterface;
    resetValues();
    mDisplayedValue = value;
    setFormula("");
}

private void resetValueIfNeeded() {
    if (mResetValue)
        mDisplayedValue = "0";

    mResetValue = false;
}

private void resetValues() {
    mBaseValue = 0;
    mSecondValue = 0;
    mResetValue = false;
    mLastKey = "";
    mLastOperation = "";
    mDisplayedValue = "";
    mDisplayedFormula = "";
    mIsFirstOperation = true;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    mCallback.setValue(value);
    mDisplayedValue = value;
}

private void setFormula(String value) {
    mCallback.setFormula(value);
    mDisplayedFormula = value;
}

private void updateFormula() {
    final String first = Formatter.doubleToString(mBaseValue);
    final String second = Formatter.doubleToString(mSecondValue);
    final String sign = getSign(mLastOperation);

    if (sign.equals("√")) {
        setFormula(sign + first);
    } else if (!sign.isEmpty()) {
        setFormula(first + sign + second);
    }
}

public void setLastKey(String mLastKey) {
    this.mLastKey = mLastKey;
}

public void addDigit(int number) {
    final String currentValue = getDisplayedNumber();
    final String newValue = formatString(currentValue + number);
    setValue(newValue);
}

private String formatString(String str) {
    // if the number contains a decimal, do not try removing the leading zero anymore, nor add group separator
    // it would prevent writing values like 1.02
    if (str.contains("."))
        return str;

    final double doubleValue = Formatter.stringToDouble(str);
    return Formatter.doubleToString(doubleValue);
}

private void updateResult(double value) {
    setValue(Formatter.doubleToString(value));
    mBaseValue = value;
}

public String getDisplayedNumber() {
    return mDisplayedValue;
}

public double getDisplayedNumberAsDouble() {
    return Formatter.stringToDouble(getDisplayedNumber());
}

public String getDisplayedFormula() {
    return mDisplayedFormula;
}

public void handleResult() {
    mSecondValue = getDisplayedNumberAsDouble();
    calculateResult();
    mBaseValue = getDisplayedNumberAsDouble();
}

public void calculateResult() {
    if (!mIsFirstOperation)
        updateFormula();

    switch (mLastOperation) {
        case Constants.PLUS:
            updateResult(mBaseValue + mSecondValue);
            break;
        case Constants.MINUS:
            updateResult(mBaseValue - mSecondValue);
            break;
        case Constants.MULTIPLY:
            updateResult(mBaseValue * mSecondValue);
            break;
        case Constants.DIVIDE:
            divideNumbers();
            break;
        case Constants.MODULO:
            moduloNumbers();
            break;
        case Constants.POWER:
            powerNumbers();
            break;
        case Constants.ROOT:
            updateResult(Math.sqrt(mBaseValue));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    mIsFirstOperation = false;
}

private void divideNumbers() {
    double resultValue = 0;
    if (mSecondValue != 0)
        resultValue = mBaseValue / mSecondValue;

    updateResult(resultValue);
}

private void moduloNumbers() {
    double resultValue = 0;
    if (mSecondValue != 0)
        resultValue = mBaseValue % mSecondValue;

    updateResult(resultValue);
}

private void powerNumbers() {
    double resultValue = Math.pow(mBaseValue, mSecondValue);
    if (Double.isInfinite(resultValue) || Double.isNaN(resultValue))
        resultValue = 0;
    updateResult(resultValue);
}

public void handleOperation(String operation) {
    if (mLastKey.equals(Constants.DIGIT))
        handleResult();

    mResetValue = true;
    mLastKey = operation;
    mLastOperation = operation;

    if (operation.equals(Constants.ROOT))
        calculateResult();
}

public void handleClear() {
    final String oldValue = getDisplayedNumber();
    String newValue = "0";
    final int len = oldValue.length();
    int minLen = 1;
    if (oldValue.contains("-"))
        minLen++;

    if (len > minLen)
        newValue = oldValue.substring(0, len - 1);

    newValue = newValue.replaceAll("\\.$", "");
    newValue = formatString(newValue);
    setValue(newValue);
    mBaseValue = Formatter.stringToDouble(newValue);
}

public void handleReset() {
    resetValues();
    setValue("0");
    setFormula("");
}

public void handleEquals() {
    if (mLastKey.equals(Constants.EQUALS))
        calculateResult();

    if (!mLastKey.equals(Constants.DIGIT))
        return;

    mSecondValue = getDisplayedNumberAsDouble();
    calculateResult();
    mLastKey = Constants.EQUALS;
}

public void decimalClicked() {
    String value = getDisplayedNumber();
    if (!value.contains("."))
        value += ".";
    setValue(value);
}

public void zeroClicked() {
    String value = getDisplayedNumber();
    if (!value.equals("0"))
        addDigit(0);
}

private String getSign(String lastOperation) {
    switch (lastOperation) {
        case Constants.PLUS:
            return "+";
        case Constants.MINUS:
            return "-";
        case Constants.MULTIPLY:
            return "*";
        case Constants.DIVIDE:
            return "/";
        case Constants.MODULO:
            return "%";
        case Constants.POWER:
            return "^";
        case Constants.ROOT:
            return "√";
    }
    return "";
}

public void numpadClicked(int id) {
    if (mLastKey.equals(Constants.EQUALS))
        mLastOperation = Constants.EQUALS;
    mLastKey = Constants.DIGIT;
    resetValueIfNeeded();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.btn_decimal:
            decimalClicked();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_0:
            zeroClicked();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_1:
            addDigit(1);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_2:
            addDigit(2);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_3:
            addDigit(3);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_4:
            addDigit(4);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_5:
            addDigit(5);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_6:
            addDigit(6);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_7:
            addDigit(7);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_8:
            addDigit(8);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_9:
            addDigit(9);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Logcat

```
02-11 20:18:59.116 6438-6438/com.example.stins.calculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.stins.calculator, PID: 6438
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.stins.calculator.CalculatorImpl.numpadClicked(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.example.stins.calculator.MainActivity.numpadClicked(MainActivity.java:105)
                                                                                at com.example.stins.calculator.MainActivity.numpadClick(MainActivity.java:101)
                                                                                at com.example.stins.calculator.MainActivity_ViewBinding$16.doClick(MainActivity_ViewBinding.java:192)
                                                                                at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I can't seem to find what is making the program crash. Does anyone see anything? I appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
CalculatorImpl calc = new CalculatorImpl(this);
```

and replace with:

```
mCalc = new CalculatorImpl(this);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm! Would you mind giving me a quick explanation one why that original statement failed like that? For future notice.

Comment: you create a new `CalculatorImpl` object named `calc` in `onCreate` method, and use `mCalc` object which is not assigned. that's why it gives the error.

Comment: Ohhh okay. Thanks so much!